# Add multiple clickable zones in a listview row

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I want to implement a row for a listview with two click zones with some special requirements:

What I want to implement is something like:

[image]

With the following click config:

- The red zone links the user profile
- The blue zone links the item detail
- Clicks over the yellow zone are ignored
- When clicking the blue zone all the row is selected (like with a background=`?attr/selectableItemBackground`)

I have tried several configs but I do not get all the points:

**Config A:** Add a clicklistener over the blue container and another over the red container, works nice but the full row selected effect when clicking the blue zone is missing.

**Config B:** Add a clickListener over the full row and another clicklistener over the red container, also works but the clicks over the yellow zone are not ignored.

How can I accomplish that?

Note: Also tried to use the Config B with an empty click listener over the yellow container. But sounds weird to add a clickListener to ignore it, and my real view is more complex than that and I should add a lot of empty clicklisteners. The ideal behavior should be the blue container to propagate its click status to the rowView

Comment: add a click listener to your adapter & make a callback in activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with either **A** or **B** just with minor addition

**A** :

> Call listview method `void setItemsCanFocus(false)` so when you click on Blue part, whole row will get focus

**B** :

> Override `isEnabled()` method in your custom or base adapter and return `false` for the Yellow part. This will block click events to Yellow part

I hope your error will fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So A works but you want to get rid the on pressed color ?  If so add this in your ListView XML.

```
    <ListView
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to implement a layout with Two Sub Layout in which One Contains the Avatar and another contains your data , while in Your Adapter Class You should have to add the tag with Specific Layout id and also add the OnClickListener for that Layout and then while You click the Layout You got the Tag and based on that Tag You are able to handle Your view in ListView Item.